# How do I start Opera 12.17 browser with only tray icon?

Tags: windows, opera, notification-area

I'd like to run opera at Windows startup.

I have enabled the option to show the icon in the notification area.

Now I'm looking for a way to avoid windows at startup, so that I can receive emails, and open the main window by clicking it. Maybe some command line option...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not just NOT start it with Windows and instead pin an icon to your taskbar instead of depending on the system tray icon?

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to close Opera 12 to tray.

We utilize this command and let a VB script open Opera and as soon Opera is open, press this key combination to close it to tray.

#### OperaToTray.vbs

```vbs
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   'Create object
strCommand = chr(34) & "D:\Opera Mail\operamail.exe" &chr(34)  'Set app path
objShell.Run strCommand, 1, false              'open application

Do                                             'start infinite loop
If objShell.AppActivate("Opera Mail") Then     'check if window is active
    objShell.SendKeys "^+%h"                   'Send Alt + CTRL + SHIFT + H
    Exit Do                                    'and exit loop/script
End If                                         
WScript.Sleep 100                              'wait 100ms (to try again)
Loop                                           'loop if no match was found
```

#### Notes

1. The AppActivate method tries to activate an application whose **Windows title** is the nearest match to `strApplicationTitle` so it might not be 100% accurate if there are multiple Opera Windows
2. If you plan to switch from Opera to [Opera Mail (Standlone client M2)](http://www.opera.com/computer/mail), you can use this method too.
   If you add `Show Exit Dialog=2` to `..\OperaMail\profile\operaprefs.ini` the Mail client will always minimize to tray if you click the X (close)
3. You can generalize this VB script to close every application by using
   `objShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"` instead which presses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

<sub>Thank you very much for the question.. From now on, I'll use this for my Opera Mail client too.</sub>

#### Used resources

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23462968/935614
- http://ss64.com/vb/run.html
- http://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47.aspx

Comment: For Note 2, the `Show Exit Dialog` setting goes in the `[User Prefs]` section of the INI file.